# Iterate through dynamic properties from IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an Attribute Validator that, given a list, must ensure that the list have at least one element.

So, I have this for the moment

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var list = value as IList;

    if (list != null)
        return list.Count >= 1;

    return false;
}
```

My problem is that, I can receive a list with more than one element, but the properties of all these elements are null, so I need to iterate over each property to check them. And I'm not really sure how can I achieve that without knowing the name of the property.

Comment: What object are you getting? A custom one? If so, couldn't you also provide a property called `IsEmpty`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by properties. Do mean the actual elements of the list should not be non-null or do you want to check each property of each element for non-null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, you have a custom type. Firstly, use it in your method declaration and don't use an object. Type casts as well as boxing and unboxing are expensive:

```
public override bool IsValid(IEnumerable<MyType> myObjects)
```

Secondly, enhance your own type by a property called `IsEmpty`:

```
public class MyType
{
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            // define here when your type is empty
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then your final check is simple:

```
public override bool IsValid(IEnumerable<MyType> myObjects)
{
    return myObjects != null ? myObjects.Any() : false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, is a custom type, and I was using an object because I needed to use this with more than one viewModel, so I was looking for a more general solution. But I guess that I will give it a try this way and I let you know, thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend working with IEnumerable, just because it works with collections other then lists.

But besides that. You can use the enumerator, which is present on every enumerable. As soon as you find the first non-null elements, return true:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var list = value as IEnumerable;
    var enumerator = list != null ? list.GetEnumerator() : null;

    if (enumerator != null)
        while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            if(enumerator.Current != null)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

on second thought, you could probably do that nicer. By calling `Cast<object>()` on your list you get a generic `IEnumerable<object>` on which you can use all the mighty of linq and just call `Count(e => e != null)` on your enumerable:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var list = value as IEnumerable;
    var enumerable = list != null ? list.Cast<object>() : null;
    return enumerable != null && enumerable.Count(e => e != null) >= 1;
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Where do you check for child properties  being empty/null?

Comment: im counting all non-null elements with `enumerable.Count(e => e != null)` on the last line (second example... the first returns true as soon as it finds a non-null element in the enumerator)... actually forgot the >= 1 before, fixed that

Comment: sorry, just realized i missread the question... I'm gonna fix that tomorrow if an answer is still required by then... need to sleep now...